# Disable Event Receiver While Updating item in list

Tags: event-receivers

I am performing multiple update on the same list item and each time when i update the item, Event Receivers gets triggered.  I need to update the item but at the same time I also want to event receiver to be disabled for multiple update. 
I am updating the item using a visual webpart using server object model.

Please suggest if there is a way to disable the event receiver using C#

Comment: https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/ check this, I hope this work for you.